# Singleclick error on OpenLayers

Tags: python, javascript, openlayers

I have OpenLayers 3.0 map with vector layer(Heritage Layer). I am trying to popup the details of the Heritage while clicking on the location of the heritage.
The Problem is: clicking on the symbol of the heritage does not click on the layer.

```
 var view = new ol.View({
projection: projection,
center: [84.101, 28.44],
zoom: 6.8
```

});

```
map = new ol.Map({
layers: layers,
target: 'map',
overlays: [overlay],
controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
  new ol.control.ScaleLine({
    units: 'metric',
    target: 'scale'
  }),
  zoomToExtentControl,
  new ol.control.FullScreen()
]),
view: view
```

});

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
element: element,
positioning: 'bottom-center',
stopEvent: false
```

});

```
map.addOverlay(popup);

var HeritageLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
id: 'heritage',
title: 'heritage',
visible: false,
legendPath: 'webatlas:district_wgs_update',
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/webatlas/wms?service=WMS',
    hidpi: false,
    params: {
        'VERSION': '1.1.0',
        'LAYERS': 'webatlas:heritage',
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous'
})
});

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  console.log("hey");

// Attempt to find a feature in one of the visible vector layers
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, HeritageLayer) {
    return feature;
});



if (feature) {
  alert("I am an alert box!");
  }

else {
        console.log("Feature Not displayed");
      
    }

});
```

Here in this code Feature Not displayed is only displayed while clicking on the heritage layer.

Comment: This is not enough of a code to try to guess where it gets wrong. Please edit your question and add more relevant code.

Comment: https://astuntechnology.github.io/osgis-ol3-leaflet/ol3/03-GEOJSON-INFO.html @TomazicM This is the code I followed.

Comment: The code you followed is for GeoJSON vector layer, but you have tile raster layer, so it's not possible to get client side feature properties on click event. See how this can be done with WMS tile layer: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html